# Storybook+css module integration in next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, css-modules

I am building a storybook repo and using module CSS for my components. when I run the storybook repo it's working fine the CSS is working fine but when I publish my storybook to use it as an NPM package in my next.js app then the next.js app throwing an error: CSS Modules cannot be imported from within node_modules.

Comment: Are you using `next-transpile-modules` to transpile your package in the Next.js app?

Comment: No i am not using it